# What does it mean sum of the Indicator random variable times something?

Tags: summation, random-variables, sorting

I am studying quick-sort and analysis its expectation.

---

The following is quick sort's recurrence.

$$
T(n) = \left\{
\begin{array}{ccc}
T(0) + T(n-1)+\Theta(n),\ \ if\ \ 0:n-1\ \ split\\
T(1) + T(n-2)+\Theta(n),\ \ if\ \ 1:n-2\ \ split\\
.\\.\\.\\
T(n-1) + T(0)+\Theta(n),\ \ if\ \ n-1:0\ \ split\\
\end{array} \right.
$$

and my text book shortened the equations above like this:
$$
X_k = \left\{
\begin{array}{align}
1,\ \ if\ \ Partition\ generates\ a\ k:n-k-1\ split\\
0,\ \ otherwise
\end{array} \right.\\
\therefore T(n)=\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}X_k\left(T(k)+T(n-k-1)+\Theta(n)\right)
$$

---

What is difference between next two?
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}X_k\left(T(k)+T(n-k-1)+\Theta(n)\right)\\\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}\left(T(k)+T(n-k-1)+\Theta(n)\right)$$

---

I think that the right equation is the following:
$$
T(n)=T(k)+T(n-k-1)+\Theta(n),\ where\ k\in\{0, 1, 2, \cdot\cdot\cdot, n-1\}
$$

Comment: The difference is that the indicator ensures that only one of the $n$ terms survives, while the second sum is adding up all the terms. The indicator is thus a shorthand for the $n$ if conditions you have. The equation you have written is incorrect: It says $T(n) = T(k) + T(n-k-1) + \Theta(n)$ **for every** $k$, and that isn't the same as the first big block of recurrence relations you wrote down.

Comment: @stochasticboy321 Oh, thank you. I got it. $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^{n-1}X_k$ means only one of $\left\{X_1, X_2, X_3, ..., X_{n-1}\right\}$. Thank you very much. Actually, I tried to find some books about indicator random variables in my school's library. But I found just mathematical definition of that. So I cannot understand. Thank you.

Comment: You're welcome :). Indicators are super useful in probability, you'll probably end up seeing more if you ever take a class on it. To make things more exact, only one of $X_0, X_1, \dots, X_{n-1}$ is not zero, so $\sum X_k =1$ always, and $\sum X_k A_k$ would be equal to $A_k$ if $X_k$ is $1$ and all others $0$.